# Getting Substring in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, substring, python-2.x

I have a string `fullstr = "my|name|is|will"` , and i would like to extract the substring "name".
I used `string.find` to find the first position of '|' like this:

```
pos = fullstr.find('|')
```

and it return 2 as the first position of '|' .  I want to print substring from `pos` position until next '|'. There's `rsplit` feature, but it return the very first char from right of string, since there're many '|' in my string. How to print the substring?

Comment: if you want to split the input on `"|"`, then simply use `sullstr.split("|")`, which would result in `["my", "name", "is", "will"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use [**`find`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) if you want, find first position of `|` and next one:

```
fullstr = "my|name|is|will"
begin = fullstr.find('|')+1
end = fullstr.find('|', begin)
print fullstr[begin:end]
```

Similar way using [**`index`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index):

```
fullstr = "my|name|is|will"
begin = fullstr.index('|')+1
end = fullstr.index('|', begin)
print fullstr[begin:end]
```

Another way is to find all occurrences of `|` in your string using [**`re.finditer`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) and slice it by indexes:

```
import re

all = [sub.start() for sub in re.finditer('\|', fullstr)]
print fullstr[all[0]+1:all[1]]
```

You can also take a look into [**`re.search`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

fullstr = "my|name|is|will"
print re.search(r'\|([a-z]+)\|', fullstr).group(1)
```

There is an interesting way using [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
fullstr = "my|name|is|will"
all = [p for p, e in enumerate(fullstr) if e == '|']
print fullstr[all[0]+1:all[1]]
```

And the easiest way just using [**`split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) or [**`rsplit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
fullstr = "my|name|is|will"
fullstr.split('|')[1]
fullstr.rsplit('|')[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
fullstr.split("|")[1]
```

which will break the string apart at the "|" marks and return a list.  Grabbing the second item (lists are 0-indexed, so this is index 1) will return the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Use the split() method to break up a string by one character.

```
fullstr.split('|') == ['my', 'name', 'is', 'will']
```

And then what you want is here:

```
fullstr.split('|')[1] == 'name'
```